# Use case for play-services-base google play service

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am bit confused about use case of

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
```

From the [play service documents](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) it says this is for `Google Actions, Base Client Library`

Questions are:-

1) Use case for this Particular Service?

2) If it is base client Service, Does that means if we have already added this library we wont need to add any sub library/service like location?

**Edit:- Corrected Service name**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it says this is for Google Actions, Base Client Library

No, it does not. That is GCM, Google Cloud Messaging. `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base` is "Google Actions, Base Client Library".

I am going to assume that you really meant `play-services-base`, not `play-services-gcm`, given your title.

> Use case for this Particular Service?

It is used internally by other specific Play Services dependencies. I am not aware of any place where you would use this yourself directly, though Play Services is vast and I may be missing something.

> Does that means if we have already added this library we wont need to add any sub library/service like location?

No. Instead, if you have a dependency on something else (e.g., `play-services-gcm`), it will probably pull in `play-services-base` for common code.

Comment: Thanks, first of all I am obliged that you answered my question. Yes you are correct, I copied wrong service....

Follow up question  >> Do you mean we dont need to add play-service-base in gradle file, and if need other services will pull up this by their own?

Comment: @AANKIT: "Do you mean we dont need to add play-service-base in gradle file" -- correct. Gradle supports "transitive dependencies", which means if we depend upon A, and A depends upon B, that we will also automatically depend upon B. For example, in 8.4.0 of the Play Services SDK, `play-services-gcm` depends upon `play-services-base` and `play-services-measurement`. Just by depending upon `play-services-gcm` in your app will pull in those other two artifacts automatically.

Comment: Thanks, That makes sense. Have a wonderful day and weekend Mr. Murphy.

Comment: this is old version of GooglePlayServices needed for example for GoogleMaps when 8.4 was the most recent lib version. Nowadays one can add just 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$some_version' as dependency and maps will work without this "base" library